# Launching Xamarin iOS app fails with log message "An error occurred searching types for the given assembly"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

### Summary

I'm trying to develop an iOS app in Visual Studio based on Xamarin Forms, but what I'm finding is that the app fails to launch on my phone when I try to run it. I have a valid iOS development certificate and I've been able to launch the app in the past, although I'm not sure what could have changed between then and now (I've been working on it very on and off).

The error I'm getting within Visual Studio's debug console is `Launch failed. The app '<<app name>>' could not be launched on '<<my iPhone>>'. Please check the logs for more details.`

I've included the Xamarin logs further down.

### Environment

I'm developing my project in Visual Studio on a Windows 10 PC. I'm using a MacBook Pro on the same network as the Xamarin Mac agent, and that's connected by USB to an iPhone 6s Plus which serves as the build target.

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
- Xamarin 4.1.1.3
- Xamarin.Android 6.1.1.1
- Xamarin.iOS 9.8.1.4
- Macbook Pro with OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 acting as Xamarin Mac agent
- XCode 7.3.1 (on Mac agent)
- Xamarin Studio 6.0.2 on Mac agent (no updates required on stable channel)
- iPhone 6s Plus (device target)

**Installed Nuget packages**

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="modernhttpclient" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="rda.SocketsForPCL" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="WebSocket.Portable.Core" version="1.2.6" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="WebSocketSharp" version="1.0.3-rc10" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.1.114" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
</packages>
```

### Further Details

When I try to execute my app, I get the following error logs. The root cause seems to be that it cannot find the C# type `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`:

```
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Forms.Intellisense.ProjectTypeResolver Error: 0 : [2016-08-07 22:07:07.7530] An error occurred searching types for the given assembly
System.TypeLoadException: Cannot find type System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception in module System.dll.
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyModule.ResolveTypeRef(ITypeReference typeReference)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyTypeReference.GetResolvedTypeWorker()
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.TypeProxy.GetResolvedType()
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.TypeProxy.get_Module()
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyTypeDef.Equals(Type other)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.TypeWrapper.Equals(Type o)
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyTypeDef.IsValueTypeHelper()
   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyTypeDef.IsValueTypeImpl()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.TypeWrapper.IsValueTypeImpl()
   at System.Type.get_IsClass()
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Forms.Intellisense.ProjectTypeResolver.<SearchTypesAsync>b__19_0() in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\34a92cd0\source\xamarinvs\src\Features\VisualStudio.Forms.Intellisense\ProjectTypeResolver.cs:line 184
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient Error: 0 : [2016-08-07 22:07:11.4859] An error occured on the receiver while executing a post for topic xvs/idb/4.1.1.3/launch-app and client vs11512david
Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingRemoteException: An error occured on client IDB4113 while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.1.1.3/launch-app ---> Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MonotouchException: warning HE0041: Error while processing device notifications: NotificationCallback with unknown message: 5

  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch+<RunAsync>d__6.MoveNext () <0x7566158 + 0x007e3> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x1bd7530 + 0x0001f> 25562 in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch+<DeployAsync>d__4.MoveNext () <0x75c41b8 + 0x0032f> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x1bd7530 + 0x0001f> 25562 in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Handlers.LaunchAppMessageHandler+<RunMTouchAsync>d__17.MoveNext () <0x75c3a18 + 0x0021b> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x1bd7530 + 0x0001f> 25562 in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Handlers.LaunchAppMessageHandler+<ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceWithoutAssetsAsync>d__16.MoveNext () <0x75c2478 + 0x001db> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x1bd7750 + 0x0001f> 25569 in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Handlers.LaunchAppMessageHandler+<ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceAsync>d__14.MoveNext () <0x75c1880 + 0x004b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x1bd7750 + 0x0001f> 25569 in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Handlers.LaunchAppMessageHandler+<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext () <0x75c10e0 + 0x0039f> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () <0x18a92a0 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`2+<HandleAsync>d__5[TMessage,TResult].MoveNext () <0x75605c8 + 0x003d7> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x18a9720 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager+<>c__DisplayClass17_0`2+<<RegisterHandlerAsync>b__1>d[TMessage,TResult].MoveNext () <0x755fc08 + 0x002bb> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x18a9720 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient+<ReplyAsync>d__34`2[TRequest,TResponse].MoveNext () <0x755ec90 + 0x00383> in <filename unknown>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__23`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__22`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__26`2.MoveNext()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.IdbClient Error: 0 : [2016-08-07 22:07:14.0450] Launch failed. The app 'TestCubeWebMobileiOS' could not be launched on 'David's iPhone'. Please check the logs for more details.
Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MonotouchException: warning HE0041: Error while processing device notifications: NotificationCallback with unknown message: 5

  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch+<RunAsync>d__6.MoveNext () <0x7566158 + 0x007e3> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x1bd7530 + 0x0001f> 25562 in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch+<DeployAsync>d__4.MoveNext () <0x75c41b8 + 0x0032f> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x1bd7530 + 0x0001f> 25562 in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Handlers.LaunchAppMessageHandler+<RunMTouchAsync>d__17.MoveNext () <0x75c3a18 + 0x0021b> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x1bd7530 + 0x0001f> 25562 in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Handlers.LaunchAppMessageHandler+<ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceWithoutAssetsAsync>d__16.MoveNext () <0x75c2478 + 0x001db> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x1bd7750 + 0x0001f> 25569 in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Handlers.LaunchAppMessageHandler+<ExecuteOnPhysicalDeviceAsync>d__14.MoveNext () <0x75c1880 + 0x004b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x1bd7750 + 0x0001f> 25569 in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Handlers.LaunchAppMessageHandler+<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext () <0x75c10e0 + 0x0039f> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () <0x18a92a0 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`2+<HandleAsync>d__5[TMessage,TResult].MoveNext () <0x75605c8 + 0x003d7> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x18a9720 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager+<>c__DisplayClass17_0`2+<<RegisterHandlerAsync>b__1>d[TMessage,TResult].MoveNext () <0x755fc08 + 0x002bb> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x18ab6f0 + 0x00035> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8f10 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e70 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x18a8e20 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () <0x18a9720 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient+<ReplyAsync>d__34`2[TRequest,TResponse].MoveNext () <0x755ec90 + 0x00383> in <filename unknown>:0
```

**Update**

After upgrading to Xamarin 4.1.2.18 based on [Marcos' response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38819379/1636276) I find that I still can't debug my app but I get a different error log output, posted [here](http://pastebin.com/3sprfanr) (because I can't fit it within this post body).

It does still complain about not finding `Win32Exception`, however.

**Update 2**

I *can* build and launch Xamarin iOS apps that are developed on my Macbook Pro within Xamarin Studio

I *can* successfully launch and debug my (actual) Xamarin Forms app using an iOS simulator from my Windows machine (this is actually really useful if I can't resolve this bug).

I *cannot* successfully launch/debug my actual Xamarin Forms app on my actual iPhone from my Windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update to the latest alpha release is 4.2.0.413 - installed on both Windows machine and Xamarin Mac Host

Comment: I did do a full check on both systems before asking, but it's possible you're right and I missed something. Xamarin Studio had a bunch of updates which I've now installed (it says no more updates on stable channel). However, according to [this page](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-7-service-release-1/) there's a Xamarin for VS 4.1.2 out and I only have 4.1.1.2.

It's midnight here so I'll upgrade tomorrow and see if it changes anything. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried again after upgrading to Xamarin 4.1.2.18 but it still complains I'm afraid (updated original post).

Comment: try this, if is a app cross platform and you have the android version compile if don't generate a error. The problem is the version in the xamarin in the mac update the xamarin in the mac.

Comment: Both versions compile okay - it's just a problem with launching the  iOS version on my device. It actually even successfully installs the app on my phone, I just can't debug it while it's running. What you suggest is a good idea, though, and right now I'm trying to create a basic "Hello, iOS" Xamarin iOS project.

Comment: read this information I'm debugging my apps in a mac mini. I hope help you  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging_in_xamarin_ios/

Comment: Cheers for the link. I read through it and tried a few things but nothing helped me much. I added `-v -v -v` to the mtouch arguments, but that didn't yield any extra logs - I think it would only do that if startup actually succeeded. Similarly, breakpointing won't work as it doesn't actually enter any part of my code. I did look at the device logs on XCode but it only had one recent crash log relating to my app, and looking at it didn't help out much - just that last night at about 11:30 PM one of my attempts to run it resulted in `EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)`

Comment: You try to create other project a compile again. Because is weird. That look like the project is corrupt.

Comment: I don't think it's a project corruption as my project is under version control and I tried rolling back to previous versions that I know were working. I get the same error each time. Sample applications also fail. I think that [this](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41655) is similar to what I'm experiencing - possibly a bug with Xamarin themselves. I'll try updating from the alpha channel to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Updating to the latest alpha release worked! Marcos, if you want to post an answer like "Update to the latest alpha release" I'll be happy to update/accept it since you more than deserve the reputation gain for all the help you've given me. (edit: latest alpha release is 4.2.0.413 - installed on both Windows machine and Xamarin Mac Host).

Comment: @Tagc really thanks you. I edit the answer I'm glad you solved the problem.

Always available to help.

Answer (score 0):

I have install the version of Xamarin 4.1.2.18

Try Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> others in the windows try (Check now) for the new stable updates.

Answer (score 0):

xvs/idb/4.1.1.3/launch-app   if you watch in the error I saw a version lower to the update in your VS2015, both xamarin need to be in the same version in the mac and the windows.

Make sure when you conect with the Xamarin Mac Agent have the same version that you have in your windows

[image: Mac Agent]

Comment: Yeah I corrected that version problem earlier today. I'm using version 4.1.2.18 now, same as you. http://imgur.com/a/5IzU7 . I've also posted a short update on my question.